# Prevent the Facebook App Posting to Secure Canvas URL

Tags: php, html, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I would to create a simple facebook app that is a form like this:

https://apps.facebook.com/koweb_test_form/

The problem is when it first enter the page it is posting to it, and since it is a form it will check the posting data

Therefore , how to prevent posting / am I confused about the logic for that so I need to change the implementation

Here is the controller code:

```
public function index()
    {
        $data = array();

        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST') {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('q1_ans', 'Answer for question 1', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('q2_ans', 'Answer for question 2', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</a><strong>', '</strong></div>');

            if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
                $data_insert = array(
                    'q1_ans' => $this->input->post('q1_ans'),
                    'q2_ans' => $this->input->post('q2_ans'),
                    'fb_id' => $this->input->post('fb_id'),
                    'name' => $this->input->post('name')
                );

                if ($this->input->post('email') != "") {
                    $data_insert['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
                }

                $data['flash_message'] = $this->Ans_model->add_ans($data_insert);
            }
        }

        $this->load->view('home',$data);
    }
```

And for frontend it is just a simple form code

Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: Don’t just check if the request method was POST, but check for the existence of a specific parameter value as well – for example for the one generated by your form’s submit button, or for a special value transfered by a hidden input field in your form.

Comment: yes there is a sign_request parameter